# Collecting all AWS EBS volume details in csv format

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3

I am trying to create a boto3 script to fetch the EBS volumes details like (VolumeID,InstanceID) and am not able to get an idea on how to use the paginate since there are more than 50 EBS volume . Please help

Comment: What is the script? Why it does not work? Any errors?

Comment: I am running the below script from Lambda but it is listing only 5 EBS

import boto3

b = boto3.session.Session()
ec2 = b.client('ec2')

page_iterator = ec2.get_paginator('describe_volumes').paginate()

for page in page_iterator:
    for vol in page['Volumes']:
        print(vol)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `describe_volumes()` method seems to return up to 500 volumes.

You can call the function again, passing the `NextToken` that was returned from the previous call into the `NextToken` field of the subsequent call. This will continue from where the previous result set finished.

Alternatively, you can use the [`describe_volumes()` paginator](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Paginator.DescribeVolumes):

```py
import boto3

ec2_client = boto3.client('ec2')

paginator = ec2_client.get_paginator('describe_volumes')

response_iterator = paginator.paginate()

for page in response_iterator:
    for volume in page['Volumes']:
        print(volume['VolumeId'])
```

Comment: That worked . Can you also help me with the correct syntax for paginate filter : Currently it is only listing in-Use

response_iterator = paginator.paginate(Filters=[{'Name': 'status', 'Values': ['in-use']}])

How do I add available also ?

Comment: `Filters=[{'Name': 'status', 'Values': ['available', 'in-use']}]`